# error on php artisan migrate laravel

Tags: php, laravel, enums

I am using Laravel and I  have migration with function:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('article_title',100)->change();
    });
}
```

and when i do **'php artisan migrate'** on my cmd i get error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]   Unknown database type enum requested,
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform    may not support it.

I don't even use enum! And I also don't have any other migrations that are not migrated and have enum.

Comment: Did you create this table before ? If not, you need to create it  Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('article_title',100)->change();
        });

Comment: i have this table and also have this column, but want to change length from 50 to 100 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've had this issue before. The problem is that the `Schema` class provided to the `database migration` factory is actually an abstraction of the `Doctrine\DBAL\Schema` class, and not a direct duplication.

When you first ran `composer install`, there were several "recommended" dependencies that you should install. No one ever does, but eventually you might find some small bug and spend hours on it, only to realize *Hey...Maybe I should try those other optional dependencies*?

Don't be like me. Instead, try what I've outlined below.

You need to directly add `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",` (or whatever stable version exists at the time of reading) to your `composer.json` file under `"require": {`.

Once you've added that line, do a composer update, and then add this line to your migration:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema
```

After doing this, you shouldn't see that error anymore.

Comment: dont really help :/ actually it doesnt even find that
Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema
and i have already had doctrine/dbal in my composer

Comment: @Danielius When you `typehint` use Schema` in your IDE, do you not see this there? If you check your vendor directory, is it there? If not, then you need to re-install the package.

Comment: i have doctrine in vendor and in that doctrine folder i have dbal, but in it there are just two folders: bin and lib, if youre asking about it i am reinstalling it now

Comment: It should [look something like this](http://i.imgur.com/nyQlErd.png), and inside of that `Schema` directory is the `Schema.php` file which is where you need to `use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema`.

Comment: yea i have it then, but now when i migrate i get error:   [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema::table()

Comment: Rob wrote that none of my table's columns should be enum, but i have one. maybe i should change it to int. but how to do it? can i just do it without migration?

Comment: We use `enum` in a few projects where we've moved them to Laravel, and you can do this, there's just some labor required. I would, however, suggest moving away from `enum` type columns if you can, as they're really just a headache to manage, and we've come so far (in 2016) that we have no real need for `enum` anymore.

Comment: i just have enum "checked" with values "yes" and "no", so can i manually change it in phpmyadmin? i will change it to int

Comment: Make sure you adjust the migration file, too. That will resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

The column itself does not have to be enum, but *ANY* column in the table cannot be enum.

Here is the line from the renaming columns section of the Laravel documentation:

**Note: Renaming columns in a table with a enum column is not currently supported.**

Answer (score -1):

Link to the documentation of Laravel: [Changing columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#changing-columns). You need to add **doctrine/dbal** to your **composer.json** file.

> Note: Before changing a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file.

Or run this command:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Comment: Yes, as I posted in my answer above, I've outlined this in detail. Your answer is a duplicate.